# Proper way to use Final Field in RealmObject

Tags: java, android, realm, final

I wanted to use final field in RealmObject like `private final int fieldName`. Because, I want to use constants and methods efficiently.

#### CleanTime.java

```
public class CleanTime extends RealmObject {

    private final int NIGHT_TIME_LECTURE_MINUTE_LENGTH = 50;
    private final int NIGHT_TIME_LECTURE_BREAK_TIME_MINUTE = 10;

    // and other field

    public CleanTime() {
        // Constructor which use NIGHT_TIME_LECTURE_MINUTE_LENGTH
    }

    // and other methods
}
```

But the problem is my Logcat throws the error which said "this class contains illegal final field"

So, I had found some documents about realm and got the reason why it doesn't work.

**In Realm official document..**

> Currently, **Realm models have no support for final**, transient and volatile fields. This is mainly to avoid discrepancies between how an object would behave as managed by Realm or unmanaged.

So, I have tried to solving this problem and below codes are completed which is using `Instance Initializer`

#### CleanTime.java

```
public class CleanTime extends RealmObject {

    private int NIGHT_TIME_LECTURE_MINUTE_LENGTH;
    private int NIGHT_TIME_LECTURE_BREAK_TIME_MINUTE;

    // and other field

    { // Instance Initializer
        NIGHT_TIME_LECTURE_MINUTE_LENGTH = 50;
        NIGHT_TIME_LECTURE_BREAK_TIME_MINUTE = 10;
    }

    public CleanTime() {
        // Constructor which use NIGHT_TIME_LECTURE_MINUTE_LENGTH
    }

    // and other methods
}
```

But I am curious whether this is **proper, realm recommened** way to use final field. Am I doing right? Is there any better idea?

Ah, above codes is same as `NIGHT_TIME_LECTURE_MINUTE_LENGTH = 50` I want to fix `NIGHT_TIME_LECTURE_MINUTE_LENGTH` field and don't want it to be changed

Comment: Nah, it should be `private static final int` and it'll work

Comment: Realm automatically ignore `static final` final fields. Also we added support for `transient` fields in the last update. They are just being ignored now instead of being disallowed altogether.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Oops....... I cannot understand myself why I was making so- easy mistake... Thank you.... I forgot `static`.... :(

Comment: @ChristianMelchior You mean brand new version which will be 3.3.2 supports `transient`? What I write in block quote is from Realm official website which said 3.3.1 is latest.

Comment: Transient fields are supported 3.2.0+